# Swift3 iOS -How to search for a URL inside an Array of URLs [URL?]

Tags: ios, arrays, url, search, swift3

I have an array of urls. I want to search for a specific element inside that array and if it's there remove it.

```
let urls: [URL?] = [url_0, url_A, url_Purple, etc..]

//first search for url_A
if urls.contains(where: url_A){
     //second remove it from the array
     urls = urls.filter{$0 != url_A}
}
```

I tried `try` and `do-try-catch` but they didn't work out. I know I'm doing this wrong and that's why I'm asking the question.

I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected arguement type '(URL)'
>   throws -> Bool

How do i search for a url inside an array of urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based your question, you can do this:

```
 let urls: [URL?] = [url_0, url_A, url_Purple, etc..]
 //second remove it from the array
 urls = urls.filter {$0 != url_A}
```

This will search for `url_A` and if found it will remove it and return new array. If I am correct, that is what you are looking for.

Based on the error which you got answer would be:

```
let urls: [URL?] = [url_0, url_A, url_Purple, etc..]

//first search for url_A
if urls.contains(where: {$0 == url_A} ) == true {
     //second remove it from the array
     urls = urls.filter{$0 != url_A}
}
```

Notice that it expects a closure as param in contains block. You were passing `URL?` type.

Comment: thanks for the help! i was initially trying {$0.someProperty == url_A} but since I couldn't find one I put the question. I'm glad I did as your response will help others! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear that.